# Trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger wherein it will insert a new row to a ADMIN_EMAIL_DOMAINS table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER email_domain_insert AFTER INSERT ON USERS
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USR_EMAIL, '@', -1) as domain FROM USERS) as a WHERE a.domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.USR_EMAIL, '@', -1)) THEN
        INSERT INTO ADMIN_EMAIL_DOMAINS (DOMAIN_NAME, VISIBLE) VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.USR_EMAIL, '@', -1), 1);
    END IF;
END //
```

What I would like to do is everytime I create a new user, i would check its email extension and then insert it to ADMIN_EMAIL_DOMAINS table if that DOMAIN_NAME is not yet existing.

My problem is it has an SQL error when i tried to execute it

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your      MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a MySQL error even if it looks right 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could suggest you another way - make field `DOMAIN_NAME` as unique and try to insert new domains into the table `ADMIN_EMAIL_DOMAINS` with [IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) option, e.g. -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER email_domain_insert
  AFTER INSERT
  ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT IGNORE INTO ADMIN_EMAIL_DOMAINS (DOMAIN_NAME, VISIBLE) VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.USR_EMAIL, '@', -1), 1);
END    

DELIMITER ;
```